# Unable to pass a variable into alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have an array of names   in 'names' . I am trying to display an alert when the user taps on a table cell. If the user touches the first cell then ,[names objectatindex:0] should be the message in the alert view.  Here is what I have done

```
 UIAlertView *okAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ok" message:@"You have just tapped [names objectatindex:0]" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    okAlert.tag=0;


    [okAlert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

In the message it is not displaying the name. I couldn't figure out the problem. Could you please help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIAlertView *okAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have just tapped %@.", [names objectAtIndex:0]]
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message:@"You have just tapped [names objectatindex:0]"
```

You've hidden that code inside a string constant. Now it's just letters.

Try:

```
UIAlertView *okAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ok" 
  message:[@"You have just tapped " stringByAppendingString:names.firstObject]
  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
```